# fullcalendar add button to event typescript angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, button, fullcalendar

Trying to have a button on an event working. For some reason I can't trace, it executes as soon as the events render.

```
initCalendar() {
  function onInteract (id) {
    console.log(id);   // <----- Executes once everything is rendered (not good)
  }
  this.calendarOptions = {
    ...,
    ...,
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      ...
      ...
      listedUsers.forEach(function(a) {
        const member = teamMembers.filter((o) => o.member._id === a.employeeMetadata.name)[0].member;
        event.description = '' +
          '<div class="text-center">' +
          '<button mat-button style="width: 80%;' +
          '    color: black;\n' +
          '    background-color: lightskyblue;\n' +
          '    font-weight: bold;" (click)="' + onInteract(member) + '">' +
          member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName +
          '</button>' +
          '</div>';
        element.find('.fc-bg').append('<br>' + event.description)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I need the function to execute only when I click the button in question

Assistance?

**EDIT**

This is what it looks like with the original set up (above code):

[image: Original set-up]

And this is my code with the new set-up (following ngzone method)

```
listedUsers.forEach(function(a) {
  const member = teamMembers.filter((o) => o.member._id === a.employeeMetadata.name)[0].member;
  event.description = element.find('.fc-bg button[mat-button]').click(() => onInteract(member));
  element.find('.fc-bg').append('<br>' + event.description)
})
```

Now the buttons do not show on the events.
I didn't implement the ngZone yet though (it's new to me). Does it have anything to do with it? Am I on the right track here?

**EDIT 2**

```
listedUsers.forEach(function(a) {
  const member = teamMembers.filter((o) => o.member._id === a.employeeMetadata.name)[0].member;
  event.description = element.find('.fc-bg')
  .append('<br><div style="text-align: center">' +
  '<button mat-button style="width: 80%;' +
  'color: black;' +
  'background-color: lightskyblue;' +
  'font-weight: bold;">' + member.firstName +  ' + ' + member.lastName +
  '</button></div>').click(() => onInteract(member));
  element.find('.fc-bg').append(event.description)
})
```

[image: Multiple buttons]

Now button isn't executed on initiation but on click, 
But it's not really the button executing, but the whole element.
When I attempt to click the button, it actually clicks the element itself and interacts with all of its' buttons. Means I get 3 interactions on the most left element and 1 interaction on the most right.

I still do not understand :)
But also, I don't understand how to make the buttons be above the element. I tried to `position:relative` it and `z-index` to `999999999`

Comment: Use a boolean variable which changes on click of the button. Use *ngIf in your div to render it after button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now solved

@estus and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240871/how-to-add-close-button-to-the-event-block-in-fullcalendar) thread helped significantly, thank you

eventRender function became this:

```
listedUsers.forEach(function(a) {
  const member = teamMembers.filter((o) => o.member._id === a.employeeMetadata.name)[0].member;
  element.find('.fc-bg')
  .append('<br><div style="text-align: center">' +
  '<button mat-button style="width: 80%;' +
  'color: black;' +
  'background-color: lightskyblue;' +
  'font-weight: bold;" id="' + member._id + '">' + member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName +
  '</button></div>');
})
```

And added eventClick function:

```
const listedUsers = assigned.filter(function(o) {
  return this.indexOf(o.employeeMetadata.name) > -1;
  }, teamMembers.map((o) => o.member._id));
  listedUsers.forEach(function(a) {
  const member = teamMembers.filter((o) => o.member._id === a.employeeMetadata.name)[0].member;
  if (jsEvent.target.id === member._id) {
    onInteract(member)
  }
})
```

Now it's all good

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected. This

```
'    font-weight: bold;" (click)="' + onInteract(member) + '">'
```

executes `onInteract` function, because it is being called.

Moreover, `(click)` cannot be used here because this piece of HTML code isn't compiled by Angular compiler.

Click event handler should be set up manually, something like:

```
element.find('.fc-bg button[mat-button]').click(() => onInteract(member))
```

Notice that since the callback runs outside a zone, it needs `ngZone.run(...)` in order to be integrated with the rest of Angular component.

Comment: Hey, It sounds cool. though I'm not sure how then to implement it.. I appended an edit